# collect all rows with same id and concatenate in into one row by creating new columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning sql and i am facing a problem with the following question.

I want to get all rows with same id into one row, explanation with example is given below

this is the table i have:

```
+----+------+------+
| ID |  A   |  B   |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | 232  | 34   |
|  1 | 456  | 1234 |
|  2 | 786  | 38   |
|  2 | 567  | 456  |
|  2 | 2    | 5689 |
|  3 | 5    | 234  |
+----+------+------+
```

And this is the output i am looking for

```
+----+-----+------+------+------+-----+-------+
| ID |  A  |  B   |A2    |  B2  |  A3  |  B3  |etc....
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | 232 | 34   | 456  | 1234 | NULL | NULL | 
|  2 | 786 | 38   | 567  | 456  | 2    | 5689 |
|  3 |   5 | 234  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----+------+------+-----+------+-------+
```

Thank you in advance, all efforts are appreciated

Comment: This is PIVOT. It is not implemented in MySQL and must be emulated. Because the output structure is dynamic (you cannot fix it because max. amount of duplicates may vary) you must use stored procedure which builds needed output. But I **strongly reccommend** to create this pivot output on the client side using its reporting subsystem.

Comment: Instead of making it dynamic, if i wanted max columns upto B3, how do i go about doing it?

Comment: Enumerate the rows partitioning by ID in CTE then use conditional aggregation. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot+%22conditional+aggregation%22 PS. You must define some ordering expression which will fix relative rows ordering, if not then your output will be non-deterministic. Current visual ordering is fake, it not exists in practice, and next SELECT may return the rows in another order.

Comment: There isn't anything in the published data which would allow you to say id=1,232 should pivot to column A and id=1,456 should pivot to A2 (etc) do you have another column which would allow this eg an auto_increment column?

Comment: id=1,232 goes to A, id=1,456 goes to A2 based on increasing values of column B, basically data is sorted on col B. Table is grouped on id and ordered on col B and then i want to concatenate rows into one row

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand why you have to do that, but here it is:

```
-- prepare your data
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, A INT, B INT);
CREATE TABLE r_table (id INT, A INT, B INT, b_rank INT);
INSERT INTO my_table(id, A, B)
VALUES (1,232,34),
(1,456,1234),
(2,786,38),
(2,567,456),
(2,2,5689),
(3,5,234)
;
-- rank rows by B
INSERT INTO r_table (id, A, B, b_rank)
SELECT id, A, B, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY B) AS b_rank
FROM my_table
;
-- query your results
SELECT split_1.id, split_1.A, split_1.B, split_2.A AS A2, split_2.B AS B2, split_3.A AS A3, split_3.B AS B3
FROM (
    SELECT t.id, t.A, t.B
    FROM r_table AS t
    WHERE b_rank = 1
) AS split_1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.A, t.B
    FROM r_table AS t
    WHERE b_rank = 2
) AS split_2 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.A, t.B
    FROM r_table AS t
    WHERE b_rank = 3
) AS split_3 USING (id)
```